# Bash command substitution syntax (for script to determine my global ip)

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm new to scripting and I'm stuck. I need to convert this:

```
MYIP=`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr'| awk '{print $2}' | cut -d ':' -f 2`;
```

Into this:

```
MYIP=curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

I'm "making" a script that will send me an email whenever my external ip changes. I'm putting it together from bits and pieces I find on the net but I can't get this to work. The first code just sends me a notification with my internal IP.

Second piece of code is for determining my global IP but it doesn't seem to work. I get the error message:

```
./filename.sh: line 5: -s: command not found
```

*(line 5 is the second piece of script posted above)*

Please help me solve the last piece in the puzzle.. Thanks.

Comment: for starters you are missing a ` ` and a ; , check your syntax ;)

Comment: Well, I've been playing around with that.. The line as it is in my post is what gives me the global ip in terminal. I thought it looked odd aswell but adding what you suggested just gives me further errors, for example: ./filename.sh: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./filename.sh: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I thought it best to keep the command to what I know "works"(in terminal) because I've done all the experimenting on my own that I can come up with. And that's why I'm here.. Thanks though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Bash's **command substitution** in both lines.

```
MYIP=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr'| awk '{print $2}' | cut -d ':' -f 2)
MYIP=$(curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//')
```

You already used the `` ` ... ` `` command substitution syntax in your first line, but the `$( ... )` syntax is usually recommended over that one.

You may read on about Bash's two syntaxes of command substitution there:
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've spent SOO many hours on this and now it finally works! And thanks for the added links. I'll keep on reading and learning =)

Comment: @GingerServer Instead of writing "Thank you" comments, please just accept the answer by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of it. You should also read our [tour] page where you can learn thee most important facts about how this site works. Thank you for joining!

Comment: I tried that but my rep wasn't high enough to be allowed to "vote". Thanks again..

Comment: Voting and accepting are two different things. Click the grey circle button with a tick symbol on it, everybody can accept answers to their own questions. It's also described in the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what ByteCommander has already said, you don't need so much piping. Just let `curl` give output to `awk` and it can handle the job. You could either use one pipe or `bash` process substitution. I used last one

```
 awk -F ':' '{print "Current IP:"substr($2,0,14)}' < <(curl -s checkip.dyndns.org)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to get your current global IP without having to strip away any extra characters with `awk` or `sed` or anything is with `dig`:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

That will return nothing but your IP.